# Add mqtt protocol to artemis Wildfly

Tags: module, wildfly, mqtt, activemq-artemis

I want to use mqtt with Artemis activemq. I tried adding a module for mqtt exactely like in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427558/how-to-work-with-mqtt-in-wildfly).
My problem is the same, I can't see the **Adding protocol support for: MQTT**.

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you try using ActiveMQ Artemis standalone rather than embedded in Wildfly.  The version in Wildfly is based on 1.5.x which has some bugs (specifically in relation to MQTT).  Standalone Artemis should be more stable and easier to configure (since it supports MQTT out-of-the-box).

Answer (score 0):

Artemis supports MQTT v 3.1.1

Please take a look at official documentation of Artemis it has complete section on how to add MQTT support to Arteis. This is [Link](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/1.5.3/protocols-interoperability.html) to official documentation